# how to perform average for similar group of entries in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
+----------+--------+
| emp_name | rating |
+----------+--------+
| Sameer   |      4 |
| Sameer   |    9.8 |
| Sameer   |      9 |
| Sameer   |      7 |
| Sameer   |    8.2 |
| Sameer   |    9.5 |
| Sameer   |     10 |
| Ashwath  |      9 |
| Ashwath  |      4 |
| Ashwath  |      9 |
+----------+--------+
```

I just started learning SQL and I wrote a query and got the above output but i want to display the averege rating of Sameer and Ashwath instead of rating, how can i do it?

Query:

```
SELECT
    emp_name,
    bus.rating
FROM employees
JOIN drives
    ON employees.emp_id = drives.emp_id
JOIN bus
    ON bus.bus_no = drives.bus_no
WHERE
    drives.emp_id IN (select emp_id from drives group by emp_id having count(bus_no) > 2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just aggregate by employee and take the average rating:

```
SELECT
    emp_name,
    AVG(bus.rating) AS avg_rating
FROM employees
INNER JOIN drives
    ON employees.emp_id = drives.emp_id
INNER JOIN bus
    ON bus.bus_no = drives.bus_no
WHERE
    drives.emp_id IN (SELECT emp_id FROM drives
                      GROUP BY emp_id HAVING COUNT(bus_no) > 2)
GROUP BY
    emp_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are learning SQL, it's better to do the right things :

Try to always use INNER JOIN OR LEFT JOIN. Using IN is more "expensive" than doing an INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN.
Last, when you use an aggregate function (COUNT, SUM, AVG) you need to use a GROUP BY
 If I rewrite your query here is what I would do :

```
 SELECT
        emp_name,
       AVG(bus.rating)
 FROM employees
 INNER JOIN drives on employees.emp_id=drives.emp_id 
 INNER  JOIN
   (select emp_id, count(bus_no) from drives
     group by emp_id having count(bus_no) > 2 ) AS   d 
        ON drives.emp_id = d.emp_id
 INNER   JOIN bus
        ON bus.bus_no = drives.bus_no
  GROUP BY emp_name
```

Here is a famous image to explain all the joins [image: Sql Joins]

Comment: Thanks for the tip Daniel but I still am very confused with joins, hopefully i'll get to know them better in near future.

Comment: When you write JOIN you are doing an INNER JOIN, but it's more "readable"

Answer (score -1):

SELECT emp_name, avg(rating) FROM table GROUP BY emp_name

Comment: Thanks that you add your Query after my solution.

Comment: @SameerAhmad That depends on what your definition of the word `it` is :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the final query is select emp_name,avg(bus.rating) from employees join drives on employees.emp_id=drives.emp_id join bus on bus.bus_no=drives.bus_no where drives.emp_id in(select emp_id from drives group by emp_id having count(bus_no)>2) group by emp_name;

Comment: i was overthinking it and thanks for pointing out what i was missing. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
$sql = "SELECT emp_name, AVG(rating) as avg_rating FROM table_name GROUP BY emp_name";
```

Comment: Where do you see the PHP tag?

Comment: thank you, didn't think of that, thanks for pointing out though!

Comment: What is `table_name` supposed to represent here?  Nothing in the OP suggests that this is the answer.